# How to run .exe from pre-push git hook?

Tags: git, githooks

So here is what I've got after searching on google for more than 4 hours :

`#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/bin/sh.exe
echo $SHELL
echo "here we go"
./PrePush/GitHook.exe`

and the console tells me:

`/usr/bin/bash
here we go
.git/hooks/pre-push: line 4: ./PrePush/GitHook.exe: No such file or directory`

My .exe is located at: `C:\Users\myUsername\Documents\MyRepos\ProjectName\.git\hooks\PrePush\GitHook.exe`
But it could be any path on my co-workers drive, so I have to use a local path.

I already tried bin/bash.exe, using the full path, using `system(./PrePush/GitHook.exe)` (because I thought it is a perl script)
but all of them raised erros.

And there seems to be no example of "just" calling a local .exe from a git hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git hooks are not executed from the `.git/hooks` folder. You must specify the correct path to your executable.

```
"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/hooks/PrePush/GitHook.exe"
```